# Hardness for problems with non constant input parameters.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computational-complexity

It's well known that problems like $3$-sat and $4$-sat and probably $k$-sat for $k\geq 5$ are NP-hard problems but what happens for example if i was to consider something like $\lceil \mathrm{log}(n) \rceil$-sat where the number of literals in each clause grows as a function of $n$ (number of variables), is it difficult to prove hardness of such a result?

Another example might be deciding if a graph has a clique of size $k(n) \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ where $n$ is the number of vertices. Is it difficult to prove hardness of problems of this form where input parameters are non-constant? Could anyone provide links where results like these are proved? Any references are highly appreciated.

Comment: You might be interested in ​ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity . ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 1):

NP-hardness of your $\lceil \log n\rceil$-SAT follows immediately by the fact that $\lceil \log n\rceil \ge 3$ whenever $n\ge 5$ -- and instances with less than $5$ variables are easy anyway.

(Note that you can convert a $k$-SAT instance to a $K$-SAT for $K>k$ simply by adding redundant literals to each clause.)

$k(n)$-CLIQUE is hard for at least some choices of $k$. For example, if you have an efficient $\lfloor n/2\rfloor$-CLIQUE solver and want to find an $m$-clique in a graph with $n$ vertices, then

- If $m<\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ keep adding new vertices and connect them to everything. Now look for an $(m+1)$-clique in the resulting $(n+1)$-graph. Adding $1$ to each of $m$ and $n$ will make $2m=n$ after at most $n$ of these steps.
- If $m>\lfloor n/2$ just add *unconnected* vertices until $2m=n$.

However, for other functions $k$, such as $k=\lfloor \log n\rfloor$ it is not obvious that $k(n)$-clique is either NP-hard or in P. The problem with generalizing the above reduction is that if you want to find a medium-sized clique in a large graph, it may take superpolynomially many added nodes to make $n$ large enough that $k(n)$ matches your desired clique size.

Comment: @ Henning Makholm thanks for the very informative response, i have one more question, to show that $\lceil \mathrm{log}(n) \rceil$-SAT is NP-hard would it suffice to prove it for a particular value of $n$? Or would it have to hold for all $n \geq n_{0}$ where $n_{0}$ is some value? I know in this case you're saying $n_{0}=5$ but would a proof of hardness for this class of satisfiability problems work if it was proved for a particular case of $n$?

Comment: x @lltl: Showing something for a single $n$ is generally not enough to prove hardness when there's always only a finite number of (nontrivial) inputs with that particular $n$. In this case, the formal content of my argument is that 3SAT can be reduced to $\lceil \log n\rceil$-SAT, in polynomial time, but this reduction does depend on having all $n$s available in $\lceil\log n\rceil$-SAT.

Comment: So if for example i was able to prove a result for an infinite sequence of $n$'s that weren't all consecutive would this still count for hardness? So by way of example if i could prove a reduction for $\lceil \mathrm{log}(n)\rceil$-SAT whenever $n=2k+1$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ would this count?

Comment: x @lltl: In order to prove your problem _hard_, you need to reduce a known hard problem _to_ it. If your reduction happens to produce instances that always have odd $n$, then of course that would work too.

Comment: @ Henning Makholm thanks for the advice, i understand the basics with regards to the reduction so i know i need to reduce a known hard problem to it. What's confusing me is situations where a problem (i.e log(n)-SAT specifically depend on a parameter which grows with input size (in this case n). But i think you've cleared this up now. So if i reduce a known hard problem to this class for an infinite number of $n$  (not necessarily of the form $n \geq n_{0}$ for some $n_{0}$) then this is sufficient for a hardness proof?

Comment: x @Iltl: What you do is reduce a known hard problem to your problem _for all possible instances of the known hard problem_, no exceptions allowed. How many $n$s of your _new_ problem you need to hit in order to make that work is up to you.